# UK tier 4 visa: Language test

Tags: united-kingdom, language, visa

I have received a PhD offer from a UK university. Since I do have my MSc from a Canadian university (but I am not canadian), the conditional offer letter does not ask me to provide any english language test. Now, does the visa application requires any language test?
As I look into the visa requirements, it seems that they excluded Canada from the list of exempted countries:
https://www.gov.uk/student-visa/knowledge-of-english

Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the same page has this statement:

**If you’re studying with a Higher Education Provider**

```
If you’re studying at degree level or above, your Higher Education Provider (HEP) 
can assess your level of English themselves. This means they may ask you to do a different test.

This must still be equivalent to a CEFR level B2.
```

If you haven't, ask the university. They'll certainly have encountered this situation before.